# How connect a Switch Button with a form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a web application and I want to implement in it a Switch Button using this [bootstrap example](https://www.bootply.com/92189), so that the user can choose the language. Also, I need it to be submitted with a POST.

How can I code this type of toggle button, e.g.,

```
  <div class="btn-group btn-toggle"> 
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default">pt</button>
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary active">eng</button>
  </div>
```

so that when the user clicks in one of them, a POST is submitted with "pt" or "eng" values?

EDIT: I just need a simple POST with redirect. I'm using Django and to translate [documention suggests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/translation/#the-set-language-redirect-view) the use of this code:

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}">
    <select name="language">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected{% endif %}>
                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

but I don't want a dropdown and the "Go" button. I would prefer the switcher.

Comment: You need to give more details. What form ? Do you have that form or only the language you want to send ? Also, do you want the request through an AJAX or simple POST (with redirect of the entire page) ?

Comment: Ok, just add more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bootstrap form as follows. I have assumed you want to validate the form using a php script (send.php). Add the name attribute, which will help you fetch the values in the validation script.

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" action="send.php" method="post">
    <div class="btn-group btn-toggle"> 
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" name="pt">pt</button>
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary name="eng" active">eng</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. How do I do that without the php validation? I not using php, but django.

Answer (score 0):

Give the buttons names and values:

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" name="language" value="pt">pt</button>
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary active" name="language" value="eng">eng</button>
```

Then read the data just like you would from your `<select>`.

Answer (score 0):

Sending only language option with a POST (through AJAX)

```js
// only if pressed a non-active button
$("button", "#language-selection").click(function (event) {
  var $btn = $(event.currentTarget)
    
  // only if not already active
  if (!$btn.hasClass('active')) {
    // you can switch the button as soon as clicked or in AJAX callback
    changeActiveButton($btn)
      
    $.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {lang: $btn.text()}, function (data) {
      // do whatever you want with your API callback data
    })
  }
})

function changeActiveButton($btn) {
  // reset active & button type on previous button
  $("button.active", "#language-selection")
    .removeClass('btn-primary active')
    .addClass('btn-default')
 
  // set active & button type on current button
  $btn
    .removeClass('btn-default')
    .addClass('btn-primary active')
}
```

```css
@import "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="language-selection" class="btn-group btn-toggle"> 
  <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default">pt</button>
  <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary active">eng</button>
</div>
```